# How do I make a UDP server constantly receive datagrams in Python

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am creating a server and client socket in Python. I have managed to send datagrams between them but I need to set the server to constantly listen for UDP messages but I can't work out how. I have seen the serve_forever() function but when I enter it, it tells me that 'NameError: name 'serve_forever' is not defined. Do I need to import something or have I missed something completely. 
I am quite new to this so wasn't sure if I needed to add anything else in.
Here is the beginning of the code:

```
     import socket

     serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

     UDP_IP = "localhost"
     UDP_PORT = 6842
     address = ("localhost" , 6842)

     serverSocket.bind(address)
     serve_forever()
     print ("Waiting for client...")
```

Comment: Why did you write `serve_forever()` there? Where did you copy / paste parts of code from? You should carefully read  the source where you copied the line from, as it would definitely contain additional info.

Comment: In all honesty, I'm not sure. This is what I am trying to figure out. I didn't know if I needed to link it to the original serverSocket or if I need to add coding into the serve_forever() brackets.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html

Comment: That might be the missing piece. I didn't import socketserver

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can replace `serve_forever()` with something this:

```
while True:
   data = serverSocket.recv(65535)
   print("Received a UDP packet containing %i bytes of data" % len(data))
```